# Incoming emails to App Engine live app are rejected

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I'm testing incoming email URLs in a new app and am stumped why they work in the dev server but not in the live app. My app files are:

app.yaml:

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.app
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: hello.app
  login: admin
```

hello.py:

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

class MailHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, msg):
        logging.info("Received a message from: %s, subject: %s", msg.sender, msg.subject)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/mail/', MailHandler),
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

The expected log message is printed by the dev server when I "send" a test email using the dev admin web interface, but when I send an email to the live app (i.e., test@myappid.appspotmail.com), it logs a 404 in the log and returns a bounce message saying "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your code with parts from a working app of mine, one difference is that my app does

```
('/_ah/mail/.+', MailHandler),
```

instead of

```
('/_ah/mail/', MailHandler),
```

And indeed, the convenience method `InboundMailHandler.mapping()` produces '/_ah/mail/.+'

Try that.

**Updated to add:** One other difference. In my `app.yaml`, I match '/.*' last. On the surface, that wouldn't seem to matter here, but it's worth placing the most general pattern last to avoid confusion when it matches instead of a more specific pattern below it.